# Content-Type header not working, Firefox always displays "Document" or "Preview Document" as the file type

Tags: php, firefox, http-headers, download, content-type

I'm using the following code to download files:

```
$file_name = $_GET['file_name'];
$file_size = filesize( 'files/' . $file_name );
$file_type = mime_content_type( 'files/' . $file_name );

header( 'Content-Type: ' . $file_type );
header( 'Content-Length: ' . $file_size );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"' );

readfile( 'files/' . $file_name );
```

And it works fine, I can download files. However, there is something that bothers me. When I download a file with Firefox, the download dialog always says that the file is a "Document", or sometimes a "Preview Document", and never an image or a PDF or whatever the file actually is. Any ideas?

Edit: I just tried with a .svg file (mime type image/svg+xml) and the dialog box correctly stated "Scalable Vector Graphics". But then I tried with a .psd file (mime type image/x-photoshop) and got "Preview.app Document". Weird. Anyone able to replicate the problem? At this point I'm thinking it might be a Firefox issue, so I added "Firefox" as a tag.

Comment: Is the script outputting anything before this code? You can not send headers after anything is output. This includes whitespace, make sure your file starts with a `<?php` with nothing in front of it.

Comment: I'm sure, just rechecked.

Comment: Also, be careful with code like this, you have a pretty big [Path Traversal vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) when blindly using user-provided file paths.

Comment: The code is simplified to make the problem clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Preview is Apple's default app for viewing lots of stuff.  If the system receiving the file didn't have Photoshop installed, it might try and use Preview instead.  If PS is installed, then make sure that 1) Content-Type header has the correct type and subtype and that 2) the filename in Content-Disposition has the correct extension.  If both of those look fine, then add the filename to the name parameter in the Content-Type header; some clients look here for the filename.